# Как связать XML и Input через JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

Есть скрипт, который "вытягивает" из XML (API) файла нужную мне информацию и ставит её в div блок.

Задумка такая, что при постепенном вводе значения в input (форму) это самое значение сравнивается с теми, что выведены из xml. Потом в отдельный блок выводятся значения, у которых начало из XML точно совпадает с введёнными значениями, а продолжение, естественное, какое есть. В общем, поисковые подсказки как в поисковиках, но без PHP. И желательно без get запросов, т.к. XML файл загружается вместе со страницей сразу. Как можно это (подсказки) реализовать?

```
   <div style="padding:3px"></div> 
   <div id="otvet"></div>   
   <script type="text/javascript">   
   $.get(   
   'http://rkvo.ucoz.ru/api/load/',   
   function(data){ 

 var mydata = new Array();   
 var i = 0;   
 $('name', data).each(function(){   
 if($(this).text()=='TITLE'){   
 if(mydata[$(this).text()] == undefined) mydata[$(this).text()] = new Array();   
 mydata[$(this).text()][i] = $(this).next().text();   
 i++;   
 }   
 }); 

   $('#otvet').html(''+mydata['TITLE']+''); 

   },   
   'xml'   
   );   
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('input').on('keypress', function() {
   var array = []
   , regexp = new RegExp('^'+$(this).val());

   for(var i=0; i < xml_values.length; i++) {
      if(regexp.test(xml_values[i])) {
         array.push(xml_values[i]);
      }
   }
   console.log(array);
});
```

Примерно. Но суть в чем: при добавлении буквы проходимся по массиву из xml и проверяем, есть ли вхождения.

Comment: Как раз то, что нужно, только как теперь вывести эти "вхождения" в отдельный блок? И ведь если он проверяет по массиву XML, то туда могут попасться и другие значения из этого XMl, а нужны только titl'ы, или я не правильно понял. В JS я разбираюсь очень плохо. Отредактировать ещё могу, а вот написать/дописать - для меня это проблема.

P.S. форма имеет такой вид: <input type="text" id="topQueryField" size="20" maxlength="50" name="q" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Поиск...';" onFocus="if(this.value=='Поиск...') this.value='';" value="Поиск..." style="opacity:0.35;"/>

Comment: @kampolWaMplr  не используйте привязки событий типа `onBlur=""` в хтмл, особенно когда используете jquery.

Comment: eicto, но в таком случае форма не возвращает данное значение, что не есть хорошо. Что в этом плохого, и какая есть альтернатива?

Comment: [кроме того](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/bhgVX/) - правда не кроссбраузерно :(

Comment: альтернатива привязывать события с помощью `.bind()`  

плохого

 - ваши функции объявлены глобально,
 - this события не указывают на элементы,
 - событийная модель jquery  не контролирует предскауемо события на элементах измененных таким образом.